# Adding a new Azure AD App Credential - What specific permissions or role memberships are needed?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to add a new password credential for my Azure AD Application, through the Powershell commandlet and I run into an insufficient permissions error.

```
New-AzureRmADAppCredential -ApplicationId "<my app guid>" -Password "<a new password>" -EndDate (Get-Date).Addyears(2)
```

Error Details

```
New-AzureRmADAppCredential : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmADAppCredential -ApplicationId "<some guid> ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-AzureRmADAppCredential], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Authorization_RequestDenied,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.NewAzureADAppCredentialCommand
```

I have the same behavior when I try to add a new secret through the UI as well.

What are the specific permissions I am missing?

Please note this Azure AD is synced with an on-prem AD. I suspect the on-prem AD permissions are also coming into play here.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you marked as an owner of the application? What directory role does your account have?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi There is no owner of the application, user access is not enabled for the application. I am a co-administrator in the Subscription. Not sure of the directory role or how i can check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update an application you must be a Tenant Administrator or marked explicitly as an owner of the application.

You can most easily check these things using the [Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/).

You can check if you are a tenant administrator of the tenant using this Graph Query:

`https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/memberOf`

And then looking for the tenant administrator directory role to be listed.

And you can check if you are an owner of the application with this query:

`https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications/{Object ID}/owners`

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I believe the Owner of the application is sufficient w.r.t to the AD at least for my purposes.